# Transfer a variable to earier point without goto

Tags: caching, php-5.3, goto, ob-get-contents

How to write this without goto:

```
ob_start();
$a = 0;
echo "START of LEFT<br />";
begin:
   if($a > 0) {
      echo "CONTENT LEFT: $a<BR />";
      <VERY DIFFICULT ALGORHITM>
       goto end;
   }
<... ALL THE REST CODE OF LEFT ...>
echo "END of LEFT<br /><br />";
$output1 = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

ob_start();    
echo "START of CENTER<br />";
$a = 5; goto begin;
end:
   <... ALL THE REST CODE OF CENTER ...>
   echo "END of CENTER<br />";
   $output2 = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();
   // print it
   echo $output1.$output2;
```

---

To get this echo:

```
START of LEFT
CONTENT LEFT: 5
END of LEFT

START of CENTER
END of CENTER
```

Requirements:

**1.** I'm not allowed to change the order(CORE( echo $a ), and PLUGIN( $a=5 )):

```
ob_start();
$a = 0;
<ANY CODE>
echo $a;
$output1 = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

ob_start();
<ANY CODE>
$a = rand(0,10);
$output2 = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

**2.** Output must be generated via ob_get_contents();

But I'm allowed to write ANY CODE in  places.

// Solvings
**ob_get_contents();** Helps only if want to replace few lines in output HTML CODE, but **can't change a value of variable**, to change the ALGORHYTM(depends of var value), which generates the random HTML code.

Also, 
As I checked my code, I understand, that my code, *even with GOTO labels statement* , **DOES NOT going to change the $output1 content** ?. How to do that? Is the only way is to recache the $output1 from his beggining. Or maybe I'm able to do this in other ways?

Comment: This code makes me very, very sad.

Comment: me too. I'm a bit confused, you seem to have asked very much the same questions a moment ago. Not so cool.

Comment: Not trully the same, similar, not the same, the other one was whole source inc. design pattern related. This one is specified in one subject - variable transfer without goto.

Answer (score 1):

You are familiar with the concept of methods/functions? If not ( and it seems that chances are.. ) you should really learn something about those first. It's then a piece of cake to split functionality out of a monolithic block of code to small, maintainable pieces of code.

Answer (score 1):

Structured programming - http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 0):

If i understood well what you want to do I would use recursive functions instead of goto. for example look at this math expression parser i've witten in C some time ago:

```
    #include <cstdio>

const long MAX = 100010;
char S[MAX], *p=S;

long eval();
long termen();
long factor();


int main() {
    FILE *fin=fopen("evaluare.in", "r");
    FILE *fout=fopen("evaluare.out", "w");

    fgets(S, MAX, fin);
    fprintf(fout, "%ld\n", eval());
    return 0;
}

long eval() {
    long r = termen();
    while ( *p=='+' || *p=='-' ) {
        switch ( *p ) {
            case '+':
                ++p;                        // go over "+"
                r += termen();
                break;
            case '-':
                ++p;                        // go over "-"
                r -= termen();
                break;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

long termen() {
    long r = factor();
    while ( *p=='*' || *p=='/' ) {
        switch ( *p ) {
            case '*' :
                ++p;
                r *= factor();
                break;
            case '/':
                ++p;
                r /= factor();
                break;
        }
    }
    return r;
}

long factor() {
    long r=0;
    if ( *p == '(' ) {                      // subexpression
        ++p;                                // go over '('
        r = eval();
        ++p;                                // go over ')'
    } else {
        while ( *p>='0' && *p<='9' )  {     // number
            r = r*10 + *p - '0';
            ++p;
        }
    }
    return r;
}
```

The main idea is to split the code in functions and where you have let's say:

```
goto apocalypse
```

you'll have:

```
Apocalypse();
```

That's the long story said short.